# Is it possible to send data to ROS from a machine not running ROS

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My problem is as follows:
I need image capture from the screen of a Mac, which doesn't run ROS well (or at all from what I can really tell). I basically need to pass in the current screenshot of the mac to ROS for further processing. I have ROS on a ubuntu VM, so basically I just need something that can very lightweight pass the screenshot data from the Mac to the VM.

I was thinking of doing this via the internet, by sending the image to a website and writing a script that will pull the image in ROS but this will have a large bottleneck.

If my problem has not been well stated, please let me know and I'll try to write it better. The short is, is there any way to create a pseudo-rostopic that doesn't need the full ros stack for images so I can get the screenshot data to ROS for further image processing (and passing the results off to a robot that runs ROS).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261818/is-it-possible-to-send-data-to-ros-from-a-machine-not-running-ros/) by [Eigen_](https://answers.ros.org/users/30403/eigen_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eigen_](https://answers.ros.org/users/30403/eigen_/) on 2017-05-16**:
Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you could write a node on the ROS machine that receives anything (video, images, files, packets, etc), using any means (sockets, serial comms, etc) and encapsulate it on the message type you need and publish a topic with it.

See [the tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) for a simple example.

---

Originally posted by [fhmrocha](https://answers.ros.org/users/25096/fhmrocha/) with karma: 11 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eigen_](https://answers.ros.org/users/30403/eigen_/) on 2017-05-17**:
Thank you! I will look into this too